# Create an alias to a slot of an object in R

Tags: r

I've bumped my head on the walls trying to create an alias (aka a pointer, or a new short nickname designating the same object in memory without copying that object) to a subpart of a complex object. Let's say I am working with an object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (package "sp"), and I want to perform operations on an part thereof, deep down in the hierarchical representation of that object. Instead of writing repeatedly things like

```
myBigMap@polygons[FRA][[1]]@Polygons[[1]]
```

I want to be able to write simply

```
mypolygon
```

so that

```
myBigMap@polygons[FRA][[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords
```

can be abbreviated

```
mypolygon@coords
```

etc. I've seen that I should maybe use environments as a replacement to the former `.Alias` defunct function, but can't find out how to tell R that I want to consider a subpart of a complex object as an environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

assignment:

```
 mypolygon=myBigMap@polygons[FRA][[1]]@Polygons[[1]]
```

doesn't create a copy until you modify something in it. So if its just shorthand for accessing the data to make some code more readable then that will be fine:

```
 mypolygon@coords
 mean(mypolygon@coords[,1])
```

neither of those will make a copy.

However, if you do modify `mypolygon`, eg by changing `@coords`, you need to put the modified value back in the structure since a copy is made:

```
mypolygon@coords = mypolygon@coords * 1000
myBigMap@polygons[FRA][[1]]@Polygons[[1]] = mypolygon
```

I think that's a preferred solution, since its just as efficient as any kind of magic aliasing scheme and its explicit since there's no magic action-at-a-distance happening.

I don't think there's any way to alias parts of an object like the way you want to do.